# How to get 'isalpha' to iterate through each character of string?

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere, isalpha

I am having trouble figuring out how to check each character in the keyword (argv[1]). I know I am probably missing something super obvious. :(

I have tried saving the string to an array, declaring a new int, but still same problem.

```
//check to make sure 2nd argument is fully alphabetic
string keyword = argv[1];

for(int i = 0, n = strlen(keyword); i < n; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(keyword[i]))
    {
        printf("Success! \n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid key, must be fully alphabetic. \n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Expected output should be "Invalid key, must be fully alphabetic." for anything not fully alphabetic. Instead, it only works for the beginning character, not the whole keyword.

Comment: That's because you `return` from inside the loop, after the first test. Pass or fail, that's all it does.

Comment: `strlen()` has to iterate the string to find the end, but you then iterate the string in any case, it is simpler and more efficient to use the string terminator directly to terminate your loop:  `for( int i = 0; keyword[i] != 0; i++ )`

Comment: You might be interested in [cs50 stack exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Don't short circuit (by `return`ing) unless the value is non-alphabetic; save printing `Success` and returning `0` for when the whole loop completes *without* exiting due to non-alphabetic characters:

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(keyword); i < n; i++)
{
    if(!isalpha(keyword[i]))
    {
        printf("Invalid key, must be fully alphabetic. \n");
        return 1;
    }
}
printf("Success! \n");
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had switch the print commands because I thought `!isalpha` wasn't executing properly for some reason, and figured I'd give it a try. What I am having real trouble with is iterating over the string to check that each character is alphabetic. I thought that was what `if(isalpha(keyword[i])` was doing, but it is not working. It is still saying `Success!` if it starts with an alphabetic character and continues on with a numeric character.

Comment: @alexa: Are you saying the code above is *still* misbehaving? If so, my only guess would be the use of a `string`, which isn't a thing in `C`. Declare `keyword` to be a `const char *` to keep it C.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was my issue. Oops. I understand now. It is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems

**Do not always exit the loop**

[@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350895/2410359)

**Use unsigned character values**

`isalpha(int x)` is defined for `x` in the `unsigned char` range and EOF.  Other negative `char` values re undefined behavior.

```
// if(!isalpha(keyword[i]))
if(!isalpha((unsigned char) keyword[i]))
```

---

With simplified loop - `strlen()` not needed.

```
int alexa_alpha_test(const char *keyword) {
  while (*keyword) {
    if(!isalpha((unsigned char) *keyword)) {
      printf("Invalid key, must be fully alphabetic. \n");
      return 1;
    }
    keyword++; 
  }
  printf("Success! \n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`isalpha(int x)` is defined for `x` in the `unsigned char` range and EOF. Other negative `char` values are undefined behavior.*  And **another** reason to never, ever use CS50's misguided `typedef char *string;` bodge.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes the CS50  `string keyword` seems to perpetuate incorrect _string_ understanding as `keyword` is not a C string, but a pointer to  (hopefully) a string - with IDB sign-ness characters.  More of the usual problems of type-defining a pointer.

Comment: @chux Oh ok, thank you for explaining in detail! That makes much more sense. Works perfectly now. I appreciate the help and clarification.